# Typed JSON serialization/deserialization in Python

Tags: python, json, serialization

```
class Person:
    first_name = superjson.Property()
    last_name = superjson.Property()
    posts = superjson.Collection(Post)

class Post:
    title = superjson.Property()
    description = superjson.Property()

# ^^^ this approach is very similar to Django models/forms
```

Then, given JSON like this:

```
{
  "first_name": "John", 
  "last_name": "Smith",
  "posts": [
    {"title": "title #1", "description": "description #1"},
    {"title": "title #2", "description": "description #2"},
    {"title": "title #3", "description": "description #3"}
  ]
}
```

I want it to build a proper `Person` object with everything inside it set:

```
p = superjson.deserialize(json, Person) # note, root type is explicitly provided
print p.first_name # 'John'
print p.last_name # 'Smith'
print p.posts[0].title # 'title #1'
# etc...
```

- Sure it should also facilitate serialization
- It should either serialize/deserialize time to/from ISO-8601 by default or be easy to achieve this in couple lines of code.

So, I'm looking for this `superjson`. Did anyone see anything similar?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[Colander](http://docs.pylonsproject.org/projects/colander/en/latest/), combined with [limone](http://pypi.python.org/pypi/limone) does exactly this.

You define a schema using `colander`:

```
import colander
import limone


@limone.content_schema
class Characteristic(colander.MappingSchema):
    id = colander.SchemaNode(colander.Int(),
                             validator=colander.Range(0, 9999))
    name = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
    rating = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())        


class Characteristics(colander.SequenceSchema):
    characteristic = Characteristic()


@limone.content_schema
class Person(colander.MappingSchema):
    id = colander.SchemaNode(colander.Int(),
                             validator=colander.Range(0, 9999))
    name = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
    phone = colander.SchemaNode(colander.String())
    characteristics = Characteristics()


class Data(colander.SequenceSchema):
    person = Person()
```

then pass in your JSON data structure:

```
deserialized = Data().deserialize(json.loads(json_string))
```

Comment: `deserialized` seems to dictionary, so I have to `deserialized["first_name"]` instead of `deserialized.first_name`, it's not exactly what I'm expecting. Looks like it's more to validator than to mapper.

Comment: Yes, sorry; colander only validates and deserializes to simple types. Updated to add the missing piece: limone.

Comment: Is it "safe" to use limone?
It has not be updated since a long time and remains in "alpha" version.

Comment: Sorry, you'll have to try that for yourself. If I'm lucky enough to start a major Pyramid project this year I'll certainly be looking at this again.

Comment: Pip couldn't install limone for today :( found code here http://pydoc.net/Python/limone/0.1a1/limone/