# Using Skue or similar frameworks to build REST API on google-app-engine

Tags: google-app-engine, rest, python-2.7

Searching for ways to build REST APIs, I found `skue` (https://code.google.com/p/skue/). However there is not much information on the site. My plan is to build a rest api as follows strictly:

```
Models << Business logics << Restful Resources.
```

What this means is: the models are access exclusively by the `business logic`; the `restful resources` interface is the only layer a client has direct access to. I am specifying all this  to avoid people suggesting using the `appengine-rest-server`.

My question is: has anyone ever successfully used Skue? If so do you have any examples you would not mind sharing? `GET` and `POST` would be sufficient, but more is welcomed. If not `Skue`, are there any frameworks out there that allow building such rest-apis on top of the google-app-engine?

Comment: Or perhaps [Typed JSON serialization/deserialization in Python](http://stackoverflow.com/q/13209909); take your pick.

Comment: It's not clear to me that they are duplicates; maybe because I am new to Python. My objects are ndb.Model objects. See edits at beginning of post.

Comment: `limone` can bind `colander` schemas to arbitrary objects, including `ndb.Model` objects, I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use json.loads() and get dictionary? In python (unlike in Java) dictionary is a first-class citizen.

As a seasoned Java programmer I was tempted, when moved to Python, to load all data into objects which I defined elsewhere, but I found that it's perfectly OK in python to get a dictionary and use it instead. It's so much easier to pass dictionaries and use them in many places (for example as keyword parameters in methods). Simply use more tests ...

In python you are moving the static compile check towards the dynamic unit-test check, and that's perfectly ok in pythonic way.